# Lodash flow && get && find together

Tags: javascript, lodash

Consider the following
`args.roleRateId` will be equal to `11604` in this case and
`args.roleRates` will be equal to an array of objects which has multipe values, consider for this exericise the follwing
`let arr = [ { id:1 , chargeRate: 200} , { id:2 ,chargeRate: 250} ]` this will be the values of our args.roleRates.
Considering the values above,can someone explain step by step what happens inside

```
flow(find({ id: args.roleRateId }), get('chargeRate'))(args.roleRates)
```

I really don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) all functions have a [fixed arity](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#fixed-arity). Arity is the number of arguments that a function can accept. Fixed arity means that the number is not dynamic.

Functions with fixed arity can be curried - ie whenever the function is invoked with a number of arguments which is less than the arity of the function, the function is not invoked, but returns a new function with an arity equals to *original arity - number of arguments*. Whenever the number of arguments is equal to the original arity, the function is invoked, and returns the result.

- `find` is a function with arity of 2, when you call `find({ id: args.roleRateId })`, a new function with arity of 1 is returned. When that function is called with a single argument (an array), find will return an actual result (the found item).
- `get` is a function with arity of 2, when you call `get('chargeRate')`, a new function with arity of 1 is returned. When that function is called with a single argument, get will return the actual result (the value of the property).

The `flow` function, receives one or more functions (flow's arity is not fixed), and returns a new function (let's call it `fn`). Whatever `fn` receives is passed to the 1st function it was created with (`find` in your case). The result of that function is passed to the 2nd function (`get` in your case), and so on (if there are more than 2). The return value of the last function (the `get`) is the result of `fn`.

Since your case you get a single `args` object, you need to manually split it, and assign it the outer `flow` function, and the internal `find` function:

```js
const { flow, find, get } = _

const fn = args => flow(
  find({ id: args.roleRateId }),
  get('chargeRate')
)(args.roleRates)

const args = {
  roleRateId: 1,
  roleRates: [{ id:1 , chargeRate: 200 }, { id:2 ,chargeRate: 250 }]
}

const result = fn(args)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

You can also create a function using `flow` that extracts the properties from args, without the need to pass them manually:

```js
const { flow, props, spread, useWith, find, identity, get } = _

const fn = flow(
  props(['roleRateId', 'roleRates']), // get an array of [roldRateId, roleRates]
  spread(useWith(find, [id => ({ id }), identity])), // create a function that takes the props array, convert the roleRateId value to { id: value } object, invokes find
  get('chargeRate') // get the chargeRate's value from the result of find
)

const args = {
  roleRateId: 1,
  roleRates: [{ id:1 , chargeRate: 200 }, { id:2 ,chargeRate: 250 }]
}

const result = fn(args)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```